# What's similar to fmap for monadic values?

Tags: haskell

This should be easy for Haskell pros..

I've got a Maybe value,

```
> let a = Just 5
```

I can print it:

```
> print a
Just 5
```

But I want to apply an I/O action to the inside of the Maybe.  The only way I've figured out how to do this without using `case` is:

```
> maybe (return ()) print a
5
```

However, this seems too verbose.  First of all, `return ()` is specific to the I/O monad, so I have to come up with a different "zero" for each monad I want to try this trick in.

I want to basically map an I/O action (print) onto the Maybe value and print it if it is `Just`, or don't do anything if it is `Nothing`.  I want to express it somehow like,

```
> fmap print a
```

But this doesn't work since `print` is an IO action:

```
No instance for (Show (IO ()))
```

I tried `Applicative`, but can't figure out if there's a way to express it:

```
> print <$> a
No instance for (Show (IO ()))
```

Obviously I'm a bit confused about monads-inside-monads.. can anyone tell me the right way to most succinctly express this?

Thanks.

Comment: Btw `print <$> a` is exactly the same as `fmap print a`,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

pelotom's answer is the straightforward one. But not the fun one! `sequence` is the Haskell function that one can think of as flipping the order of type constructors between a list and a monad.

`sequence :: (Monad m) => [m a] -> m [a]`

Now what you want is, so to speak, to flip the order of type constructors between a `Maybe` and a monad. Data.Traversable exports a `sequence` function with just that capacity!

`Data.Traversable.sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)`

This can specialize to `Maybe (IO ()) -> IO (Maybe ())` like in your example.

Hence:

```
Prelude Data.Traversable> Data.Traversable.sequence (fmap print $ Nothing)
Nothing

Prelude Data.Traversable> Data.Traversable.sequence (fmap print $ Just 123)
123
Just ()
```

Note that there's also a `sequenceA` function which is slightly more general, working not just on Monads but all Applicatives.

So why use this approach? For `Maybe` the approach that takes it apart explicitly is fine. But what about a bigger data structure -- a `Map` for example? In that case, `traverse`, `sequenceA` and friends from `Data.Traversable` can be real handy.

Edit: as Ed'ka notes, `traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)` and so one can just write `traverse print $ Just 123`.

Comment: You can just use `traverse print $ Just 123` with the same result

Comment: The source gives a simple definition for traverse: `traverse f = sequenceA . fmap f`

Comment: Thanks, I guess `traverse` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I wonder if it's useful to define a function like `traverse_` similar to `sequence_` and `mapM_`?

Comment: @Daniel Velkov, http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_ Since it discards the result (the shape of Traversable) it only needs to be Foldable

Answer (score 16):

> First of all, return () is specific to the I/O monad, so I have to come up with a different "zero" for each monad I want to try this trick in.

`return ()` is actually quite generic, as can be seen by its type:

```
Prelude> :t return ()
return () :: (Monad m) => m ()
```

I see nothing wrong with the `maybe (return ()) print a` approach.

Answer (score 2):

> But I want to apply an I/O action to the inside of the Maybe.

This can be achieved with monad transformers.

MaybeT is a monad that can be wrapped around another monad. Put another way, MaybeT can use any other Monad to abstract away (innocent[1]) failure in a computation.

Sadly, GHCi does not (in 2011) have any functionality to make playing with monad transformers easier, but here you go:

```
> :m + Control.Monad.Maybe Control.Monad.Trans
> let a = Just 5
> runMaybeT$ do { v <- MaybeT$ return a ; liftIO$ print v }
5
Just ()
```

For more in-depth understanding of monads and monad transformers, I suggest you read other sources in the web. Keep in mind monads also simply wrap values.

I'll try to keep it simple. Signatures: m = IO, a = Integer

**runMaybeT** :: MaybeT m a -> m (Maybe a) -- Turns a computation in MaybeT IO into a computation in IO.

do **{** -- do notation without indentation to make it fit on ghci's prompt[2].

**MaybeT** :: m (Maybe a) -> MaybeT m a -- Wrap a computation of type IO (Maybe Integer).

**return a** :: IO (Just Integer) -- Replace this with your computation.

**lift** -- Run the computation in the wrapped monad.[3]

**Just ()** -- The result of the computation. GHCi prints IO results whenever it is not ().

MaybeT is not included in mtl, so you might have to install it

```
cabal install MaybeT
```

Or consider [1]

---

[1] For passing error messages as well, use MonadError

[2] I know about multiline input in GHCi

[3] Use **liftIO** if you need IO from a stack of monads.

Comment: Thank you!  I really want to get more familiar with transformers.. I've already read a lot but still have difficulty understanding/knowing _when_ to use them.  I guess I'll learn if I just make use of them more often, so perhaps this is a good opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
unwrap :: (Show a) => Maybe a -> IO ()
unwrap Nothing  = return ()
unwrap (Just a) = print a
```

It will return / print the the data submitted, after unwrapping it.

Comment: @Steve - he's defining his own `unwrap` function

Comment: By the way, this will print "()" in the case where the argument is `Nothing`... I think the OP's intention was to do nothing in that case

Comment: @TaslemGuy that doesn't compile... you want `return ()`